# JavaFX WebView - not loading page

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I have created my RootLayout inside of JavaFX Sceene builder. It containst BorderPane and in it's center TabPane with three tabs. On first tab I want to have WebView. My RootController contains:

```
      @FXML
      private WebView webview;

      @FXML 
      private WebEngine webengine;
```

I have conected my WebView in RootLayout.fxml by it fx:id with webview variable.
My initialize method in RootLayoutController is (RootLayout controler is defined in fxml file):

```
   @FXML
    private void initialize() {

         this.webview = new WebView();
         this.webengine = this.webview.getEngine();
         this.webengine.load("http://www.oracle.com/us/products/index.html");

    }
```

But page is not loading. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of other questions, but I'm not able to find them in a reasonable amount of time searching.

Never initialize references that are injected using `@FXML`. Specifically, since you have

```
@FXML
private WebView webview ;
```

it is an error to then do

```
this.webview = new WebView();
```

This creates a new instance of `WebView`, which is distinct from the one you defined in the FXML file. Thus when you load the page you are loading it into the new `WebView` instance (which is not part of the scene graph).

Additionally, I doubt that you are actually creating the `WebEngine` directly in your FXML file. So I think you need:

```
@FXML
private WebView webview ;

private WebEngine webengine ;

public void initialize() {
    this.webengine = this.webview.getEngine();
    this.webengine.load("http://www.oracle.com/us/products/index.html");
}
```

If you really do define the `webengine` in FXML, then you need

```
@FXML
private WebView webview ;

@FXML
private WebEngine webengine ;

public void initialize() {
    this.webengine.load("http://www.oracle.com/us/products/index.html");
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but it turns out I was just specifying "webView" for the ID of my component in the Properties > id field in Scene Builder, when I should have entered it under Code > fx:id. Rookie mistake.